# Boot mac with os select option everytime

Tags: mac

By holding down option key while booting I can select which OS I want to boot into. This is a bit hit and miss for me, sometimes the option key is not recognised and it just boots into my default OS.

Is there a way to boot into the OS select option everytime without pressing the option key ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install [Refit](http://refit.sourceforge.net/),
which does the job for you.

Comment: Cool, ill give that a try.